# How do i make explicit wait check for page source

Tags: python, selenium

This is just an example, but I want if Hello in html source on explicit wait, how do I make it work?

```
if "Hello" in html_source:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("foobar")))
```

Answer (score 0):

[From `selenium` documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Hello']")))
    print(driver.page_source)
except:
    print("element could not be found within the 10 second timeout period")
```

If you want a better answer, I suggest you [ask a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [use examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: Hi, so just to understand correctly, by.link_text, that means if <span class="test1"> Hello </span>  exists itll know its present?

Comment: @Slownix- Yes. However it will only look for an exact match. You may want `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` depending on usage

Comment: linkText would work for only anchor tags, not for span or any other tag.

Comment: @cruisepandey Oh derp. Yeah, you're right. Searching by xpath would be the best, so I edited my answer

Comment: @Reedinationer Corrected the xpath by adding `*`, with out the tagname or * it's not a complete xpath and none of the elements will match though they exist on the page.

Comment: @supputuri Thanks! I honestly didn't know about the `*` operator, but if OP had included HTML (which they really should have) I would have put an appropriate path there instead.

Comment: That works, but it only looks for exact matches, anyway of getting partial.

Comment: @Slownix- I would look at [this post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/how-to-identify-element-with-knowledge-of-partial-text-for-any-tag-eg-div-span/18356)

Comment: @Reedinationer I hope I'm not annoying. Is it possible to make Selenium read all my list values and check if any of items from the list are in //span[contains(text(),list)]

Comment: @Slownix- Yes, that would certainly be possible through your logic in your code. I do not think that is something inherent in `selenium` though. You would probably want to create a function that takes your browser and a word as input and returns `True` or `False` if it is found. Then implement a loop such that you go through all the words in your list and feed them into your function.

Comment: @Reedinationer Yeah, I found it, guess google searchs work. Thank you.

Comment: @Slownix- Glad to hear! If this problem is solved it is standard to click the check mark by the post to accept it as the answer (you can change the selected answer later if a better post comes along too). Welcome to StackOverflow